# Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: svn, apache, xampp

I just follow instruction from http://serk01.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/how-to-create-your-own-home-svn-repository-with-xamppapache/ about creating svn repo with xampp/apache. Everything runs well except when I access http://localhost/svn it show error message.

When I view source, this is the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="160043">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

Anyone experienced like this before? What is the problems?

Answer (score -1):

Well, which version do you have? And which OS?
Here is a bug in version 1.6.6 (r40053) and you need to change permission on repo/db/db-rep.cache on 660

Comment: I use windows xp. I use TortoiseSVN 1.6.7, Build 18415 - 32 Bit , 2010/01/22 17:55:06 and Subversion 1.6.9

Comment: Well, It could be same issue, does directory have correct rights? I never tried to run SVN Server on windows, so I guess I can't help you.